# Directory.GetFiles() returns full path

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, directory

I want to return the files that are  images, inside a particular directory. I want to create the image path like this

```
  string[] ImageNames = Directory.GetFiles(path);


        string tds="";
        for (int i = 0; i < ImageNames.Length; i++)
        {
          tds += "<tr> <td> <img href=/Articles/ArticleImageStore/'" + ImageNames[i] + "' width='64' height='64'></img></tr> </td>";
        }
```

but it returns the physical path of the file on the disk. How should I do this??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx):

```
string[] ImageNames = Directory.GetFiles(path)
                                    .Select(p => Path.GetFileName(p)).ToArray();
```

This will produce a list with only the names of the files.

Comment: @SpiralsWhirls it returns an array of files. If that array has only a single element that's because there was only 1 file.

Comment: @SpiralsWhirls: silly question: do you have more than 1 file in that directory? If so, are they located in subdirectories?

Comment: hhh.. Sorry I missed to inclue the `.ToArray();` its ok now.. actually i was getting an error.

Comment: @SpiralsWhirls - The one that you found to be most helpful. Whichever it is.

Comment: or `Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, pattern)`, also; if you are in a web context you can use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath` to create a path relative to the web root.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than using the `Directory` class I would use `DirectoryInfo` then you can do this;

```
 string[] fNames = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath).GetFiles("*.png").Select(x => x.FileName).ToArray();
```

The `DirectoryInfo` version of GetFiles returns FileInfo objects rather than the file paths as strings so you can do a lot more the with the results. I happen to have a select which sort of nullifies that by just projecting a the FileName for each FileInfo instance returned by GetFiles but if you needed to do more with the files you could remove that then loop over the FileInfo objects.

Also, I'm using an overload that has a pattern which will make it easy to ignore your non image files.

DirectoryInfo docs; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63.aspx